# How to run asynchronous javascript code synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm filtering an array and storing the newly returned arrays into another array and then doing some operations but the filter function does not complete and the compiler reaches to the next line. How can I make the compiler stop until filter function completes so that I don't get undefined below.

```
            let pricePublishData = [{isInternalBp: 'Y'}, {isInternalBp: 'N'}]
            let arr1 = [];
            let arr2 = [];

               arr1 = pricePublishData.filter(item => item.isInternalBp == 'Y');

               arr2 = pricePublishData.filter(item => item.isInternalBp != 'Y');

              const fc = [];

              arr1.forEach(ca => {
                arr2.forEach(cd => {
                  if (
                    ca.bpName == cd.corporate &&
                    cd.userType == 'Grower' &&
                    cd.fulfillmentStatus == 'Not Fulfilled' &&
                    cd.itemOpenQuantityInBase > 0
                  ) {
                    fc.push(cd);
                  }
                });
              });
  
              let combinedAcquirers = [];
  
            
            const fca = fc.map({key: item.corporate, value: item.corporate});
            combinedAcquirers = [...fca, arr2.map({key:item.bpName, value: item.bpName})];
```

The problem is that the code is directly reaching to the foreach loop when arr1 doesn't have the value yet. How can I ensure that arr1 has value before it reaches foreach loop so that it doesn't thow undefined error.

Comment: Something about your description isn't adding up. `.filter` is *already* sychronous. What value are you expecting arr1 to have, and what does it have instead? I notice your last two lines aren't using `.map` correctly: you're passing in an object, not a function. Is that perhaps the problem?

Comment: to answer the question in the title, you can't run asynchronous code synchronously. Fortunately, all the code you've posted is synchronous, so the only problem you may have is the code isn't doing what you expect - for example `fc.map({key: item.corporate, value: item.corporate});` does nothing, since `.map` expects a function as the callback - you should look in the browser developer console to see the error that line of code produces

Comment: There aren't any `bpName`, `corporate`, `userType`, `fulfillmentStatus`, `itemOpenQuantityInBase` defined in your `pricePublishData`, of course nothing will be pushed by `fc.push(cd)` because the if condition never true.

Comment: I was pushing an array that I got from the API inside another array and hence was facing the problem. Code above is correct and works hence closing the question. Thanks for your comments.